# Azure Devops Release not update Azure WebApp

Tags: azure-devops

I did an initial deployment to an Azure WebApp on Linux via a direct publish from Visual Studio. The code just echoes out some text and the page comes up successfully. I can update the text in the code and re-publish. And the new text displays on the web.

Now I am trying to deploy it via Azure DevOps rather than a direct publish from Visual Studio. I created a rudimentary build and release pipeline in Azure DevOps.

I updated the text echoed out in the code then ran the build pipeline followed by the release pipeline. The Deployment status says that everything was successful. I went through the logs as well and there are no error messages. However, the website page text has not changed. Also restarted the App Service in Azure but the change is not reflected.

The release pipeline has one artifact which is linked to the latest build. And one stage which is "Azure App Service deployment" with the right subscription and the right App Service Name linked.

[Release Pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqvFb.jpg)

Any idea what I might be missing?

Here is the output from the deployment step -

> Blockquote##[section]Starting: Deploy Azure App Service
> ==============================================================================
> Task         : Azure App Service deploy
> Description  : Deploy to Azure App Service a web, mobile, or API app using Docker, Java, .NET, .NET Core, Node.js, PHP, Python, or Ruby
> Version      : 4.163.9
> Author       : Microsoft Corporation
> Help         : https://aka.ms/azureappservicetroubleshooting
> ==============================================================================
> Got service connection details for Azure App Service:'myAppName'
> Package deployment using ZIP Deploy initiated.
> Deploy logs can be viewed at https://myAppName.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/xxx/log
> Successfully deployed web package to App Service.
> Successfully updated deployment History at https://myAppName.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/xxx
> App Service Application URL: https://myAppName.azurewebsites.net
> ##[section]Finishing: Deploy Azure App Service

Thanks in advance, Jake.

Comment: Have you checked "WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE" settings on Azure appservice configuration page?

Comment: So I added WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=1 to the Appservice. At that point, the deploy failed, saying that Zip Deploy failed. So I took it out. 

There was another configuration called WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE which was set to false. I changed this to true just to see. The deployment succeeded but the text is still the old text.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to create an empty Azure Service directly within Azure. Then pushed the code to this new Azure Service via DevOps. Now it seems to be working as expected. Only other difference is that I had created this as an App for Windows rather than App for Linux. Anyway, the update is working now.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT Could you tell what happend ? I'm facing the same issue now

Comment: Hello, same here. It started out of the blue. Tried several different approaches to no avail.